# How to implement accessing a website with access code in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Suppose I have a website written in Meteor. Now I only want selected people to visit my website. Like Eventbrite's private event, only invited people can access by inputting access code.

Just curious whether there is such a feature available in Meteor. If not, could someone point me to some resource on how to proceed?

More on this:

Suppose I want to access www.a.com. In order to access its contents, I need input an access code. Otherwise, I can only see a dialog to ask me to input code.

Is this clear?

Thanks

Derek

Comment: Your question is too generic. Try providing some examples of how your app is like, and how have you tried to implement this yourself (you need to show some effort if you want people to help you).

Answer (score 0):

no, there is nothing like this. i needed something like that and ended up writing it myself.

Comment: Ditto. I used an `Invitations` collection for which the `_id` ended up being the access code. Then I could tell if the access code had been used or not. The access code was always provided via a link so people didn't have to type it in. A shorter code could also be used of course.

Comment: ah, interesting. i didn't want to automatically dump the generated ones in a collection, so i wrote an algorithm instead. it generated codes to hand out, then again to check the ones being tried. if successful, *then* i stored off the submitted code. so if a tried one got a hit on the collection, it was rejected as "already used".

Comment: In my model I wanted traceability back to the user who had issued the invitation so I had to keep that somewhere. Your approach is very slick too.